# How to add autocomplete to dynamically created inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-autocomplete

sorry for asking a question that has been answered, I read them, but I could not figure out how to apply them to my problem.

Basically I have a form with this input

```
<input class="auto" type="text" name="id_item[]" placeholder="Article ID" required style="width: 15%;"/>
```

and then I have an empty div under it, where I put newcly created inputs, when user click the add button

```
<div id="next_items">
</div>
```

My function to create and delete new inputs looks like this

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#add_item").click( function() {
        $("#next_items").append('<input class="auto" class="new_id" type="text" name="id_item[]" placeholder="Article ID" required style="width: 15%;"/>');
    });

    $("#remove_item").click( function() {
        $(".new_id:last").remove();
    });
});
```

and the last thing is my autocomplete js

```
$('input.auto').each(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: "contract/auto",
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

It works fine for my first input, which is there all the time, but when I tr to add new input with the button, it does not work. I tried using the each function and it still does not work. Also the classes started to mix up in the created buttons. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind autocomplete for that textbox after appending it:

```
$("#add_item").click( function() {
    $("#next_items").append('<input class="auto" class="new_id" type="text" name="id_item[]" placeholder="Article ID" required style="width: 15%;"/>');
    $("#next_items .auto:last").autocomplete({
        source: "contract/auto",
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```